# Excpetion when installing gofabric8 in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows, openshift, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fabric8, minishift

In my system I have enabled the Windows Subsystem for Linux(WSL) and installed Ubuntu on Windows 10.

https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8-platform/blob/master/INSTALL.md

On top of the WSL, I was trying to install the fabric8 from the scratch with the Minishift using instructions for Ubuntu in the above link and while running the below command, getting error stating that "**No User home environment variable found for os windows**"

*gofabric8 start --minishift --package=system  --namespace fabric8*

Note: Before running the above commands, I have setup libvirt and qemu-kvm in my WSL

Comment: You're installing fabric8 inside Bash on Ubuntu on Windows and it complains about not knowing the Windows home folder? That is weird...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem installing fabric8 on Windows. A look into the [sourcecode](https://github.com/fabric8io/gofabric8/blob/master/gofabric8.go#L81) reveals, you need to define a `HOME` environment variable. In windows CMD try

```
set HOME=C:\Users\yourHome
```

That worked for me

Comment: Thanks Gerald. That worked like a charm when I tried to install the gofabric8 in Windows in existing Minishift. I have to quit my adventure of using WSL.  

Comment: I set 
`HOME = %USERPROFILE%`